# Can`t open compiled project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qmake, nmake

I have compiled project with qmake (qmake -project; qmake; nmake).
When I opened file .pro, to reload project I got the following error:

> The item "debug\moc_Rls.cpp" already exists under the filter
>   "Generated Files"

Project, being part of soultion now is unavailiable when I open solution.

The evidient question: what to do?

Comment: cut and move the moc_Rls.cpp see if error still there ;)

Comment: I removed moc_Rls.cpp, error remained

Comment: See which one is the configuration file, probably the .pro .It seems like this file has been defined under two filters, remove it from one of them.

Comment: I removed .pro nothing has changed - still get the same error and can`t open project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, sorry it was my mistake I thought you were on Linux.

Follow these step:

1.Open the `[Project_Name].vcxproj.filters` file under project directory.

2.See the following lines (I am pasting mine)

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="Main.c">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="FunctBank.c">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="funcDef.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
  </ItemGroup>
```

3.Here you will see `debug\moc_Rls.cpp` defined twice under two filters.

4.One of them I can guess is

```
<ClInclude Include="debug\moc_Rls.cpp">
  <Filter>Generated Files</Filter>
</ClInclude>
```

And the other one you have to detect yourself.

After finding remove that filter and your project will run smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for information. I have done that you advised but project can`t be opened still. I use git, so it is much easier for me to rollback than to sort this issue out. Here I posted this question because that type of mistake "can`t open project" arose for the 2-nd time.

Comment: Now, it`s my own project which I wrote from scratch

Comment: The issue still occurs sometimes even with VS19. It is odd that they didn't find a way to remove those duplicates automatically all those years.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just experienced this issue so am sharing the solution.
I had used QTCreator to create a form class in another subfolder. 
In doing so the "duplicate" files had been added to  the qrc file, which for some reason QTCreator saw as the project file. Removing the entries from the qrc fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue pretty recently. Even with VS19. Deleting duplicate from filters didn't solve my issue. So to solve it you need to delete that **from .vcxproj file as well.**

Summary:

- -Delete duplicates from Yourfancyproject.vcxproj.
- -Delete duplicates from Yourfancyproject.vcxproj.filters

Then problem supposed to be fixed.